# Is there a way to store/cache an InputStream?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream

I have a method that returns an InputStream of a file on S3. If I use this method two times, a call to S3 is made twice. I am wondering if there is a way to store the inputstream?

For example:

```
InputStream getInputStreamForObject(String fileName) {
  //return inputstream for fileName on S3
}

String determineFiletype (InputStream is) {
 //some way to determine filetype from inputstream. 
 //inputstream would be read here
}

void someMethod(String fileName) {
   String fileType = determineFileType(getInputStreamForObject(fileName))
   if (fileType == "DOCX") {
     docxParser.parse(getInputStreamForObject(fileName))
   }
   else if (fileType == "XLSX") {
     xlsxParser.parse(getInputStreamForObject(fileName))
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use a BufferedInputStream with mark() and reset()

Comment: Or you can read everything to a byte array in memory, and open a ByteArrayInputStream on the byte array.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks :) this was supposed to be pseudo code. I am coding in groovy so this would work

Comment: @PeterLawrey Would that copy all contents to the memory?

Comment: @JBNizet I would prefer not to copy everythin as a whole in memory if at all possible.

Comment: @Anthony then you're out of luck.  You can either open two separate connections, or store it all in memory; there's not really any other choice.

Comment: @Anthony that will copy either as much as you read or as much as is available up to 8KB. You can make the buffer smaller. Say you make the buffer 1 KB and you read the first few bytes a few times, only the first 1 KB will be read once, no matter how large the stream is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Great. Let me review an example of using BufferedInputStream mark() and reset()

Comment: @LouisWasserman he could also write it to a temporary file on the local file system (if there is one), and re-read twice from there. But if the file type is at the beginning of the stream, Peter's solution is the simplest and fastest one.

Comment: What is the point of storing `InputStream`? Just cache the actual content and return that

Comment: Isn't `BufferedInputStream` going to internally be equivalent to storing it in memory, though?

Comment: @JBNizet something like this? `byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(getInputStreamForObject(fileName)); fileType = determineFileType(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)); docxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))`

Comment: @LouisWasserman no, it will only store a buffer in memory. Not the whole content.

Comment: @Anthony yes, assuming IOUtils.toByteArray() does the correct thing.

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer for anyone else with a similar problem. The solution is based on the comments by JB Nizet

This uses [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) to convert InputStream to bytearray

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(getInputStreamForObject(fileName)); 
fileType = determineFileType(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)); 
docxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
```